# How to feed one image after another by feed_dict in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm tring to feed an image one after another by feed_dict .
I cloned this repository https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow , and in "pix2pix.py", images are fed from a folder by tf.WholeFileReader(). But I want to feed loaded images from memory. I made a list of images which is numpy.ndarray , and using feed_dict in a for loop. But after an image fed, program does't respond.
I changed "test" part of the original code, and here is my code.

```
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

    holder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, None, 3])


    with tf.name_scope("load_images"):
        paths=[]
        paths.append(1)

        assertion = tf.assert_equal(tf.shape(holder)[2], 3, message="image does not have 3 channels")
        with tf.control_dependencies([assertion]):
            raw_input = tf.identity(holder)

        raw_input.set_shape([ None, None, 3])

        width = tf.shape(raw_input)[2] # [height, width, channels]

        #just copy for now
        a_images = cls.preprocess(raw_input[:,:,:])
        b_images = cls.preprocess(raw_input[:,:,:])

        inputs, targets = [b_images, a_images]
```

After some processing, following is session part. "arg_img" is an argument which is a list of images, and converted_outputs is an array of converted image by pix2pix.

```
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)
    #logdir = cls.a.output_dir if (cls.a.trace_freq > 0 or cls.a.summary_freq > 0) else None
    #sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=logdir, save_summaries_secs=0, saver=None)

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        print("entered sess")

        if cls.a.checkpoint is not None:
            print("loading model from checkpoint")
            checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(cls.a.checkpoint)
            saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)
        print("checkpoint loaded")



        for j, img in enumerate(arg_img):
            im=np.asarray(img,dtype=np.float32)
            print(type(arg_img))

            ret_im=(sess.run(converted_outputs, feed_dict={holder:im}))

            print("passed")
            out_img_list.append(ret_im)

    return out_img_list
```